# Waxed or unwaxed lemons?

Tags: food-safety

I use a lot of whole lemons in cooking and not sure whether waxed or unwaxed lemons are best.  I have used both but concerned about both coatings on lemons. I stopped using waxed lemons when I found unwaxed ones but they are treated with chemical fungicides and pesticides (Imazalil and propiconazol) for a longer shelf life.  These are toxic and carcinogenic! Where can I buy unwaxed and untreated lemons from?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are, but how about organic? They should be pretty much free of everything...

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate, but for the record, a chemical can be toxic carcinogenic *in sufficient quantities*, but safe in minute quantities. You eat, drink, or breathe plenty of things like that every day. The amounts of fungicides, herbicides, and pesticides you encounter in food are small enough that government agencies have found them to be safe.